# Help identifying an arcade game from the late 1980s

Tags: identify-this-game, arcade

I'm looking for an arcade coin-op game from the late 80's that I remember seeing as a child.

Game in question is a puzzle-action featuring a penguin pushing blocks of ice over smooth ice.
After a few levels, it would feature hammers on a pivot that would spin when hit by a moving cube.
This would stop the moving object, rotate the hammer and hit the cube again, now moving 90 deg from original path.

My memory is fuzzy, and I don't remember any other details.
Even so, can someone help?

Comment: I think the word “childhood” ought to be blacklisted in question titles.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sounds to me like Kickle Cubicle. The spinning hammer and ice is as you describe. I don't think he's a penguin; more of a fantasy character but otherwise it matches.

[image]

Comment: That's the one! Just checked a playthrough and I remember some of the levels.
Now I have a name to go investigate further.      
Thank You!

Comment: It's ironic, I have a NES emulator and I literally played this game from start to finish this year (2023 at the time of this post). I hadn't played it since the 90's. It was nostalgic!

Comment: It was my first "obsession" game way back when I was a kid.        
There is a free modern recreation at http://www.m3dr.com/projects/kicklec/

Comment: For anyone interested in finding videos of the arcade version, try searching for the Japanese name Meikyūjima or 迷宮島. The English name only finds videos of the NES version.

Answer (score 11):

Sounds like [Sega's Pengo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pengo_(video_game)) - though I'm not 100% sure about the hammers.

Screenshot from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ARC_Pengo_(Act_2).png):

[image: Pengo Art]

Comment: Saw that one but the graphics are off.    
I'd imagine I'm looking for a later clone.    
Can't find an image of the hammers.

Comment: I remember playing a cloned version for PC that looked slightly different, more like [this](https://www.myabandonware.com/game/pengo-2r). Note that the name was changed to Pango with an a. But also, no hammers that I recall